# Deploying django on azure - scriptprocessor could not be found

Tags: django, azure, fastcgi, wfastcgi

I am having some trouble setting up my website on Azure. My website is developed using Django and I am using wfastcgi to run it on the server; but the server keeps giving an error that says, "scriptProcessor could not be found in   application configuration." Here is the error exactly:

[image: error]

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\Python27" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="iasf.settings" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="Python27_via_FastCGI" />
      <remove name="Python34_via_FastCGI" />
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
           path="handler.fcgi"
           verb="*"
           modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python27\python.exe|D:\home\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}"
                  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```